# Using Chromecast Android API to push a URL to the "ChromeCast" App

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

So far I've been able to write a webpage that pushes a url to the (what I'm calling) native app in the chromecast device. Through this API I can open a "video_playback" app that sends the URL and some other info, just like in this webpage http://googlecast.github.io/cast-chrome/ to my device and my video plays just fine...

Now I want to do that with the Android API, but it treats that receiver "app" as if it doesn't exist. With some more poking around I found that the actual name of the app is ChromeCast, but all I've been able to do is get a blank screen or a 404 to show up. Is this not supported on the Android app? (ie I'm forced to write my own receiver) or am I doing something wrong?

I perfectly able to open a YouTube app through the Android API and load a video, so most of my code is fine. It seems I just need to figure out what application name and arguments to use in the ApplicationSession.startSession() function.

Any help would be appreciated.-

Comment: Can you please describe how you opened a YouTube video with the Android API? Can't seem to find out how to do that. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you explain how you start video_playback and push the url using your webpage?

Answer (score 1):

How are you starting your session (which version of startSession() are you using?)

It sounds like you are starting your session ok but then you need to send the url of the video  via the MediaProtocolMessageStream.loadMedia().

https://developers.google.com/cast/reference/android/javadoc/reference/com/google/cast/MediaProtocolMessageStream#loadMedia(java.lang.String, com.google.cast.ContentMetadata, boolean)

Comment: I have written my own receiver and I can load media just fine. What I want to do is load media on the default ChromeCast receiver, not my own.